# mostrar nodejs Errores dentro del html

Tags: html, nodejs

```
app.post('/Register', [
    check('EmailR')
        .not().isEmpty().withMessage('Field cannot be Empty')
        .isEmail().withMessage('Email is Incorrect')
        .normalizeEmail(),
    check('PasswordR')
        .not().isEmpty().withMessage('Password Field Cannot be Empty')
        .isLength({min: 6, max:64}).withMessage('Minimum 8 to 64 Character')
],function(req,res){
    const errors = validationResult(req)
    if (!errors.isEmpty()){
        return res.status(422).json({ errors: errors.mapped()});
    }else{
        res.send('Account Successful Create');
    }
```

estoy usando express validator. de que maneras yo puedo lograr que estos mensajes de validación me puedan salir en la misma pagina sin recargar al enviar el formulario. he visto que tienes que tener un `(template engine) como ejs o pug` para poder pasar el datos del nodejs a ejs o pug, agradezco su orientación en el tema

actualmente los mensajes se me visualizan asi
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si tu API no se encarga de renderizar el HTML, entonces el que se encarga de mostrar el mensaje es el `frontend`. Tu API ya está enviando el mensaje con: `return res.status(422).json({ errors: errors.mapped()});`. Es la aplicación del lado cliente la que debe encargarse de tomar esa respuesta y mostrarla al usuario en la vista. La pregunta es, ¿cómo consumes tu API?

Comment: es cierto pero,  el detalle es que no se como agarrar los valores del `return res.status(422).json({ errors: errors.mapped()})` y ordernarlos de manera en el frontend, en cuanto a tu pregunta pudieras explicarte mejor porque no entendi tu pregunta